# What is an environment?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I assume this question is somewhat dumb, but I can't seem to find an answer. What exactly is an "environment" in the context of Visual Studio (or similar)?

Say, for example, that I choose my Visual Studio 2013 to be configured as a C# environment (when you first install it it gives you the option), and then create a Visual Basic form application via selecting Fle>new>Visual Basic>Windows form. What would be the difference between doing that and creating the same application in the Visual Basic environment configuration?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would think that the environment is every thing you or the IDE "uses" while interacting with the VS IDE. C# and VB differ in so much, such as the compiler, the code generated by the IDE for the controls, etc. As a result creating an application using VB would generate different set of files and would require the IDE to use different parts of its code to generate the resulting application. However, the common part is the .NET Framework. Note that there is a class called Environment, but I don't think this is what you are asking about.

Comment: The difference, in your scenario, is whatever environment you pick, it will default to that when you try to make a new project. It will also configure any language specific settings to use VB.NET or C#, depending on what you choose. For example, MSDN help, the code examples.

Comment: I see. So basically, the end product would be the same, only the resources or options available and perhaps the exact details of compiling and debugging would differ, correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Actually those settings the OP is referring to doesn't alter projects in any way. It alters how the IDE displays toolbars/window panes etc. So from a code perspective nothing changes. How things are laid out in the IDE will look different. That is all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment settings you can select (and change later) only affect the look and feel of the IDE. Think of these environments as "themes" and "skins" in other applications. These **environments** in Visual Studio simply alter the default **look and feel** of the **IDE**.

You can learn more about what visual changes each of the different environments makes:

For Visual Basic see this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms172679(v=vs.100).aspx)

For Visual C++ see this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w7hc4wz6(v=vs.100).aspx)

For General Development see this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms165473(v=vs.100).aspx)

For Web Development see this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/Aa992065(v=vs.100).aspx)

You'll see that each of the links will show you what changes in the IDE you can expect. Consider all the changes **cosmetic**. They don't alter compiling/linking.